# Mobile emulator to view source code?

Tags: web-applications, android-emulator, emulation, view-source

I want to view source code on a WebApp, but when I enter the URL using my desktop, the browser it forwards to the desktop version.

I then tried the Opera mobile emulator, but it functioned in every single way of a mobile device, including not allowing me to "View Source."

Is there a way I can view a webpage on a computer but as if I am on a mobile device, but still view the code, as if I'm on a regular computer?

I've tried IE, Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, they all forward the page to the desktop version, so I can never view as mobile on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, and I found a workable solution. Summary: you can set up the Opera Desktop debugger console to work together with the Opera Mobile emulator.

See [Debugging Mobile Web Pages With Opera Developer Tools](http://www.development-cycle.com/2012/11/debugging-mobile-web-pages-with-opera-developer-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Try Mobile web browser emulator](http://www.kythuatmang.net/mobile-web-browser-emulator.php). Note you must checked the checkbox to be able to view the mobile version then you view source as usual

Answer (score 0):

You could use Opera Mobile and Opera Developer Tools, but you need to install an old version of Opera (pre-Chromium). They are available on [Opera's FTP site](http://arc.opera.com/pub/opera/).

Answer (score 0):

On a Desktop you can use the emulation feature of Chrome.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

You can also use remote debugging on devices with Android 4 and up.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging